# In Reporting Services, how do you force a report to execute when any parameter is changed?

Tags: reporting-services

I have 2 drop down parameters on my report (not linked). How do I make it so that when I change any one of those parameters the report refreshes?

I see the following options which sounds exactly like what I want, but it doesn't work...

[image: Report Parameter Properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure the screenshot is related to caching the underlying data in preview mode. I have not found a way to do what you are asking.

Comment: dang, at least I know someone else has looked into this =) thanks.